# Make Div tag clickable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Below code gives me the list of messages in table row format and i want to make each row as clickable. I have tried every suggestion in SO but could not make it work.  
As i could not make whole `tr` clickable, i made `i.reason` field as clickable as temprorary solution.

```
<% if @notifyCount > 0 %>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<% @notify.each do |i| %>
<tr class="notifyTable" id= "<%=i.id %>">
 <td class="myWidth concat"> 
    <%= image_tag "#{i.incident_image}", style: "height:45px; width:45px; float:left; margin: 0 8px 0 0" %> <b> <%= i.sender.first_name + ' ' + i.sender.last_name %> </b> <br> 
    <div> <%= link_to truncate(i.reason.capitalize, length: 50), message_member_path(id: i.id), style: "text-decoration:none" %> </div>
 </td>
</tr>
<%end%>
</table>
<%else%>
<p style="opacity:0.7;text-align:center;margin-top:5px"> No Unread Messages ...</p>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

You'll have to use Javascript to make this work

Javascript (and JQuery) basically works on the front-end of the browser (inside the `DOM` - [Document Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)) to bind events to elements on the page.

Here's how you'd made a div "clickable" using JQuery:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".div", function() {
   // Your Action Here
});
```

--

In regards to the specifics of your question, you may need to look at using the following code:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".notifyTable", function(){
   alert("Row is clicked");
});
```

This will allow you to capture the click event. If you want to then perform things with that click, you'll be best adding `data` attributes to your `row`, like so:

```
<tr class="notifyTable" id= "<%=i.id %>" data-link="http://google.com">
```

This would allow you to do this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".notifyTable", function(){
   window.location.href = $(this).data("link")
});
```

Comment: I like the approach but i want to navigate to `message_member_path(id: i.id)` path when clicking on the table row (similar to the link i am pressing on `<%= link_to truncate(i.reason.capitalize, length: 50), message_member_path(id: i.id), style: "text-decoration:none" %>` ) to navigate to particular object.

Comment: i am trying like `data-link= message_view_member_path(<%=i.id%>)` but its taking as text and showing `No route matches [GET] "/users/message_view_member_path(2144)"` and in this approach , it wont show the mouse pointer as clickable right ? it will just show as pointer and user wont understand whether its clickable.